# dompdf - Checkbox displayed but it don't displayed checked

Tags: php, dompdf, html-to-pdf

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"/><span>yes</span>
```

i have this but showing just unchecked checkbox after generate PDF using DOMPDF.
what i should do now for this??
I am using DOMPDF version - 0.7

Thank You,
Hitesh Ambaliya

Comment: This question i asked on git hub so you can check there also if i forgot to post answer here. see below link

https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1439

Comment: Dompdf 0.7 actually in use, per the github issue. Unable to reproduce so far.

Comment: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1121 The answer in this page may help you